# Material UI - The textfield in the search bar doesn't get clicked when search icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

To show the search Icon on `TextField`, this is what I've been doing:

```
                  <TextField
                        size="small"
                        id="searchCandidate"
                        data-testid="searchCandidate"
                        label={textLabel}
                        variant="outlined"
                        fullWidth
                        onChange={onChange}
                        onBlur={onBlur}
                        className={classes.searchBar}
                        InputLabelProps={{
                            classes: {
                                focused: classes.cssFocused
                            }
                        }}
                        InputProps={{
                            classes: {
                                root: classes.cssOutlinedInput,
                                focused: classes.cssFocused,
                                notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline
                            },
                            endAdornment: inputAdornment
                        }}
                    />
```

And

```
const inputAdornment = showSearchIcon ? (
    <InputAdornment>
        <IconButton style={{padding: 0}} aria-label={textLabel}>
            <SearchIcon data-testid="search_message" />
        </IconButton>
    </InputAdornment>
) : null;
```

So a search icon appears in the textfield due to the `inputAdornment`. However, if I click on the icon, the input doesn't get clicked. I should probably provide an `onclick` to  `IconButton` and handle thorugh that. Or is there a simpler way to do this?

[image]

Comment: why don't you add handle search by function onClick on icon? You can save state of value in "input" to search

Comment: @VietDinh I need the `TextField` to apeared clicked when this icon is cliked.

Comment: why do you want get clicked appear in TextField? Do you mean you want to get value from TextField to send search request?