# How to create a ref and manually trigger onclick on a textfield in React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I need to trigger click on `<TextField>` of material-UI  manually on certain event. In React I'd have been creating a `ref` and then triggered `onClick` on that ref. How do I achieve this in React Hooks?

P.S In case you're wondering, why I need to do this, this is why:
[Material UI - The textfield in the search bar doesn't get clicked when search icon is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64069188/4650975)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply assign a `ref` prop to the `TextField` and call it a day like what the other answers have described. `ref` only works on DOM elements such as `<input/>`. In a custom component you would normally need to use [Forwarded Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

However, in your case, since you are using MUI `TextField`, they already expose a prop that enables you to attach the `ref` to its internal `input` element. The prop is [`inputRef`](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props).

```js
function App() {

  const txtField = React.useRef(null);
 
  return(
    <div>
      <Button 
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={() => {
          txtField.current.focus()
          // at this point if you need to trigger click then invoke .click() instead
        }}>
        focus on text field
      </Button>
      
      <br/>
      
      <TextField inputRef={txtField} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    const { TextField, Button } = MaterialUI;
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: That makes sense because I already tried ‘ref’ and it wasn’t working. Will implement it and accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Great! I confirm `inputRef` works. I already had tried `ref` that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use react hook named `useRef` then pass the ref created to ref attribute or innerRef attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ref=React.createRef();

//click
ref.current.onclick=

<TextField ref={ref}/>
```